# Optical path difference and fringe width in Fizeau's experiment for measuring ether drag

Tags: optics, interference

In A.P. French's *Special Relativity*, page $47$ and $48$, the author described Fizeau's apparatus,

[image]

> Water is made to flow through
>   two tubes with flat glass end plates as shown, so that one beam
>   of light always travels with the water and the other beam always
>   against it. Outside the water tubes the conditions are the same
>   for both beams; thus to compute the optical path difference we
>   need only consider what goes on inside the tubes. We can calculate
>   this difference in terms of the difference of *times* for the
>   two beams. If each tube is of length $l$ and the speed of the water (refractive index $n$)
>   is $v$ (with drag coefficient $f$), we have
>   $$\Delta t=\frac{2}{(c/n)-fv)}+\frac{2}{(c/n)+fv)}\approx \frac{4n^2 fvl}{c^2}$$

Coming to the relevant part, he then said,

> This implies an optical path difference $c\Delta t$. The change of
>   optical path, expressed as a multiple ($\delta$) of the wavelength $\lambda$ of
>   the light, is thus given by $c\Delta t / \lambda$:
>   $$\delta=\frac{4n^2 fvl}{\lambda c}.$$
>   In Fizeau's experiment the approximate values were
>
> $l = 1.5$ m
>
> $v = 7$ m/sec
>
> $\lambda$ = $5.3 \times 10^{-7}$ m
>
> $n = 1.33$ (refractive index of water)
>
> $\delta = 0.23$  fringe

What did he mean by the "$0.23$ fringe"? And shouldn't $\delta$ be restricted to integers or half-integers only?

[image]